# export x, y coordinates of object in adobe pro flash

Tags: flash, adobe

I am new to flash. We have created few animations in Adobe Flash. We have created png sequence of the same. Now we need the co-ordinates of the objects so that I can run the animation through program in my cocos2d-x game. How to get those co-ordinates. For. e.g.

A player is doing some action and then land on a stone, that action has been animated in flash. So in the game at what position should I start the animation, so that It will land in stone properly at the end of the animation.

XML is not compulsory, although preffered, so that I can read the co-ordinates programatically.

Thanks,

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  What is the purpose of what you are doing? What exactly is the desired outcome?  You want a xml or text file that lists every objects position for every frame?   Please provide more details.

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully it is much clearer now.

Comment: Great. So just to be clear, you're not actually using flash player, just FlasPro as an authoring tool?  Mostly likely JSFL will be the most elegant solution. I'm not experienced with it though so someone else would have to help you if going down that road.  The only other way, would be to write a script that crawls the display tree every frame and captures the bounds of every display object.

Comment: Might be helpful to explain how you're exporting the PNG sequences.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I am not using Flash Player, I am creating the animation in Flash Pro and exporting the PNG sequence so that using those png I can get the animation in my game. Also, there are option in AdobeFlash itself export animaiton as png sequence. If you right click on animation object, it will show that option.